# ¿Por qué no me carga el menú de PHP que tengo en otro archivo?

Tags: php, html5, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

Estoy rediseñando una web utilizando Codeigniter como framework y estoy intentando aprovechar parte del código original para crear la zona de admin, pero estoy teniendo problemas para conseguir que el menú cargué en la página indicada.
La zona de admin es el punto de inicio. Aquí el administrador se loga:

```
<div id="superior">
  <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
 <span class="error"><?php if (isset($_SESSION["er"])) echo $_SESSION["er"]; ?></span>
  <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>control" method="post" name="formulario" style="margin:20px 0 0 20px">
    <p>Usuario :
      <input type="text" name="usuario" >
&nbsp;&nbsp; Contrase&ntilde;a :
      <input type="password" name="password" >
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="ENTRAR" >
    </p>
    <p><a href="password.php">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Y pasaría, como podéis ver en el código a la siguiente pagina (control.php):

```
<section class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-3 mb-5">
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$this->load->library(array('session'));
include ('configuracion.php');
if (isset($_POST["usuario"]) and isset($_POST["password"])) {

            $usuario= $_POST["usuario"];
            $pass=md5($_POST["password"]);
        
            $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM admin WHERE User = "'.$_POST["usuario"].'" AND Pass = "'.$pass.'"';  

            $consulta=mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die (mysqli_error($con));            
            $nom=mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
            $priv=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
            $data = new stdClass();
            if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta)>0) {
                if ($priv["Permisos"] ==1) {
                $_SESSION["priv"]=1;
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["priv"]=0;
                }               
                $_SESSION['valido'] = "true";
                $_SESSION['pt']=$priv["Id"];        
                $this->load->view('pages/main', $data);
            } else {                
                $_SESSION['valido'] = "false";
                $_SESSION["er"]=" Error: nombre de usuario o contraseña no válidos.";
                $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
            }
        } else {
    
        $_SESSION['valido'] = "false";  
        $_SESSION["er"]=" Acceso restringido: Indique su Usuario y Contraseña.";
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);     
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Y si todo va bien y se cumple lo indicado en la página, se cargaría main.php, que es donde se invoca al menú:

```
</div>

<div id="menu_lat">
<?php
    require_once('menus/switch_menus.php');       
?>
</div>
<div id="cont_2">

</div>

<div class="container">
```

Pero la página queda en blanco y no se carga ningún elemento en el div menu_lat.

He conseguido reparar todos los errores que han ido surgiendo y no sé si el problema está relacionado con alguno de los archivos que os he mostrado o con los que debería cargar el archio switch_menu.php que son unos cuantos:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION["men"])) {
    
        switch ($_SESSION["men"]) {
            case 1:
            include('menus/m_usuarios.php');
                        
            break;
            
            case 2:
            include('menus/m_usuarios.php');
            break;
            
            case 3:
            include('menus/m_eventos.php');
            break;
            
            case 4:
            include('menus/m_documentos.php');
            break;
            
            case 5:
            include('menus/m_reclamaciones.php');
            break;
            
            case 6:
            include('menus/m_cobros.php');
            break;
            
            case 7:
            include('menus/m_empleo.php');
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera en la que estas intentando hacerlo no es la más sostenible 
Lo que se suele hacer es, en la carpeta `application/views/` crear una carpeta dentro que se llame `partials`, ahí pondrás las vistas que quieres que aparezcan en varios sitios de tu web

Creas un archivo que se llame `header.php` y ahí metes tu menú

En tu controlador, en la función que se ejecute añades la vista del menú antes de la vista individual
Un ejemplo de esto:

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('partials/header');
        $this->load->view('home');    
    }
}
```

Aquí tienes la documentación
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html